# Python & Pandas: Re-indexing after selecing entries

Tags: python, pandas

In my initial data, there're some problematic data, and I'd like to leave them alone, so I do `df = df[(df['direction'] < 100) & (df['speed'] < 400)]`.

However, when I try to access indiviual entry like `df.ix[100]`, the data maybe `in-accessible`, because it was out-select in the condiontial selection. So I want to re-index the data, how can I do it?

And after playing it for a while, I realized that the initial query `df = df[(df['direction'] < 100) & (df['speed'] < 400)]` seems not creating a new variable but a view to the original data, which makes me more confused.

So, How can I re-index the data after queries? Or I should `drop` instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you can use `.reset_index(drop=True)` to reset the index to default consecutive integers.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# sample data
# ====================================
np.random.seed(0)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5,2), columns=list('AB'))
df

        A       B
0  1.7641  0.4002
1  0.9787  2.2409
2  1.8676 -0.9773
3  0.9501 -0.1514
4 -0.1032  0.4106


# ===================================
df1 = df[df['B']>0]  # cannot access df1.ix[2]

        A       B
0  1.7641  0.4002
1  0.9787  2.2409
4 -0.1032  0.4106

df2 = df[df['B']>0].reset_index(drop=True)  # df2.ix[2] works fine

        A       B
0  1.7641  0.4002
1  0.9787  2.2409
2 -0.1032  0.4106
```